# Assign dict contents to independent variables

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, defaultdict

How do I split a defaultdict into independent lists with keys as listnames and values as the list elements.

For example:

```
defaultdict ([('A', [1, 3, 4]), ('B', [3, 6, 8])])
```

How do I get:

```
A= [1,3,4]
B= [3,6,8]
```

Comment: Don't. [Keep data out of your variable names.](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but generally you can't and you shouldn't try to.

One obvious reason for this is that you would need to enforce that the dict keys are valid Python names (not even any string would work, let alone dealing with non-string keys).

Another reason is, even if a key *is* a valid name, you could unpredictably overwrite some other object that happens to have this name. It could be a built-in function or anything, which can break your script in any possible way.

If you are not convinced, you could try something like this:

```
In [1]: d = {'A': [1, 3, 4], 'B': [3, 6, 8]} # a defaultdict would work, too

In [2]: for k, v in d.items():
   ...:     globals()[k] = v
   ...:     

In [3]: A
Out[3]: [1, 3, 4]

In [4]: B
Out[4]: [3, 6, 8]
```

Docs to read:

- [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)
- [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)